# delete repetition in strings

Tags: c, for-loop, iteration

i want to write code in c language to delete any character in string s1 which   matches any character in the string s2 . using only for loops. that is my trial has failed -_- .
for example if s1="ahmed" and s2="omnia"  should edit s1 to >> s1="hed"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int i,j;
int k;
int counter=0;

int main()                         
{
      char s1[100];
      char s2[10];
      char temp[100];

      printf("\n enter string 1: ");
      scanf("%s",s1);

      printf("\n enter string 2: ");
      scanf("%s",s2);

     printf("\n%s",s1);
     printf("\n%s",s2);

      for(j=0;j<9;j++)
      {
         for(i=0;i<9;i++)
         {
            if(s1[i]!=s2[j]&&s1[i]!='\0')
             {
                 temp[counter++]=s1[i];      //add unique items to temp
                 k=counter;                   //size
                 temp[counter]='\0';           
             }
         }
      }
              for(i=0;i<k;i++)
              {
                 s1[i]=temp[i];
              }
        printf("\nstring 1 after delete : ");
        printf("%s",s1);
    return 0;
}
```

how can i compare one item with nested items then achieve a condition ??

Comment: Please edit your question and add one or more examples of input and expected output. And please format your code properly.

Comment: Specifically, we need an [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and the exact input/output, along with error messages, as @MichaelWalz said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you including the null character statements inside the `if` statement?
Try these two statements after the two `for` loops, like this. **And please indent your code**.

```
for(j=0;j<strlen(s1);j++) //Why is it 9 in your code? It should be the respective lengths
{
    for(i=0;i<strlen(s2);i++)
    {
        if(s1[i]!=s2[j]&&s1[i]!='\0')
        {
            temp[counter++]=s1[i];          
        }
    }
}
k=counter;                   
temp[counter]='\0';
```

and include:`#include<string.h>`

Comment: thank u all   ^_^  & any other feedbacks or answers are welcome .

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any coding errors here, only your logic is flawed.

This should work

```
for (j = 0; j < 9; j++)
{
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        if (s1[j] == s2[i] && s1[i] != '\0')
        {
            break;
        }
        else if (i == strlen(s2))
        {
            temp[counter++] = s1[j];
        }
    }
}
temp[counter] = '\0';
for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)
{
    s1[i] = temp[i];
}
printf("\nstring 1 after delete : ");
printf("%s", s1);
```

In your original code you kept reading the original string from the beginning, instead of advancing the iterator each time.

So in the first iteration you compared 'ahmed' against 'omnia' which is fine.
In the second iteration though, you compared 'ahmed' against 'omnia', instead of 'hmed' against 'omnia', and that's why you got a large repetition of the original string in your output.

Also, I'd memset the memory of s1 and s2 first to 0.